# Custom ArrayAdapter ошибка

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Реализовал свой адаптер для заполнения списка `(ListView)`.
Когда список выводит имеющиеся значения - все нормально. Но как только я добавляю в него еще 1 элемент - вылетает ошибка размера массива.
Помогите найти ошибку.

```
public class TaskArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<Task> taskList;

    public TaskArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        taskList = new ArrayList<>((List<Task>)objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View rView = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        Task task = taskList.get(position); //Exception
        ((TextView) rView.findViewById(R.id.taskItem_name)).setText(task.getName());
        ((TextView) rView.findViewById(R.id.taskItem_descript)).setText(task.getDescription());
        ((ImageView) rView.findViewById(R.id.taskItem_img_status)).setImageResource(getResPrior(task.getPrioritet()));
        return rView;
    }
}
```

---

Связывание списков, адаптеров и view:

```
    actualTaskList = DataModel.taskListActual;
    termOverTaskList = DataModel.taskListTermOver;
    allTaskList = DataModel.taskListAll;

    ArrayAdapter taskAAactual = new TaskArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, actualTaskList);
    ArrayAdapter taskAAtermOver = new TaskArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, termOverTaskList);
    ArrayAdapter taskAAall = new TaskArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, allTaskList);

    ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.taskList_actual)).setAdapter(taskAAactual);
    ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.taskList_termOver)).setAdapter(taskAAtermOver);
    ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.taskList_all)).setAdapter(taskAAall);
```

---

Метод добавления в списки нового элемента:

```
    public static void addTask(Task task){
    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    allTaskList.add(task);
    taskAAall.notifyDataSetChanged();
    if (!task.isComplete()){
        if (task.getTerm().getTime() > today.getTime()){
            actualTaskList.add(task);
            taskAAactual.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } else {
            termOverTaskList.add(task);
            taskAAtermOver.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

---

Ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ru.portal_systems.tasknote, PID: 6052
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 10, size is 10
java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
ru.portal_systems.tasknote.TaskArrayAdapter.getView(TaskArrayAdapter.java:39) //<-Кликабельно
android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2240)
android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)     android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:655)
android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5136)
android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4247)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

Понимаю, что лучше реализовать через `RecyclerView`, но найти ошибку уже принципиальный вопрос.

Comment: Кто такие `allTaskList`, `actualTaskList` и `termOverTaskList` и как они связаны с `taskList`, который в адаптере?

Comment: @post-zeew, списки, которые используются для отображения

Comment: Как они связаны с `taskList`, который в адаптере?

Comment: Они передаются в адаптеры (при инициализации)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы в своем адаптере делаете `taskList = new ArrayList<>((List<Task>)objects);` (я бы тип параметра поправил всё-таки с `List` на `List<Task>`)

это значит, что у вас в адаптере независимая **копия** списка.
добавьте в адаптер:

```
public void add(Task task) {
    taskList.add(task);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

не храните actualTaskList, termOverTaskList, allTaskList, а вызывайте так:

```
public static void addTask(Task task){
    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    taskAAall.add(task);
    if (!task.isComplete()){
        if (task.getTerm().getTime() > today.getTime()){
            taskAAactual.add(task);
        } else {
            taskAAtermOver.add(task);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ТОЧНО!!! Спасибо. вторая часть Вашего ответа не нужна, проблема была в new ArrayAdapter.